# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server etc

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting following error, when i'm trying to update things in my mysql db.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
<?php
    include("../inc/con.php");

    $postID = $_POST['postID'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $edit = mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET postTitle = '$title', postContent = '$content' WHERE postID = $postID") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: You should not use `mysql_query` in the first place, it's unsafe and deprecated. Use `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Comment: Do your content or title has a double quotes in it?

Comment: can you `echo` the sql string you're trying to execute so we can see how the variables are substituted?

Comment: Everytime you add `$vars` into mysql_query, you should not forget to [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) them, although you should consider also what @Stefano said.

Answer (score 0):

you should escape your variables first.

try this

```
$postID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postID']);

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET postTitle = '".$title."',
                                    postContent = '".$content."'
                     WHERE postID = '".$postID."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It's doesn't come with an error more, but it's still not updating it, in the database. :/

Comment: then your main problem is solved dude , your main question in title is this error.

Comment: to solve this second question you must provide your code and your tables and we will see.

Comment: This is my tables in the database: http://prntscr.com/2wu7x8


And this is the code, where i edit the posts. 

http://pastebin.com/23T8bmLi

Comment: then you must first be sure that there is values in those variables . try echo them and see if there is values , maybe $postID is empty or someone else.

Comment: I've just echoed them out, and it seems like, it's ain't getting the ID.

Comment: you see , this is basic debug dude, just try your self debug your code and if something wrong you can ask , if there is no id means will not update because there is no id that your will query will update to. Ok wish your question is solved and make sure to accept answer as main question is solved.